# working of two recursion inside a loop

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

The question is to print the number of ways chords can be drawn in a circle having 2*n points such that no two chords intersect one another

Can someone explain how the **Two recursions inside for loop** working using a recursive tree diagram?

[THE CODE OF THE PROGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOkrR.png)

Comment: copy the code and paste here, not in external sites, not in image format

Answer (score 0):

Here's the key idea of the algorithm implemented in the code you linked to:

If you place one chord, the non-intersection requirement means you've cut up your circle into to "circles", of smaller sizes, and you now need to place chords within each of them independently. The number of options for doing so is the multiplication of the number of options for each of two circles, due to the independence.